# When did the Cross of Saint Peter start being used as a Satanic symbol?

Tags: christianity

Reading the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_of_Saint_Peter) it seems unclear to me when the Cross of Saint Peter first became associated with Satanism. What is the earliest occurrence of the upside down cross being used as a Satanic or anti-Christian symbol?

In fact, Wikipedia cites a rock band and movies as the most likely candidate which doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Interesting question.  I'd have to do some serious research to determine a "when", but as to the "why", it a matter of inversion of symbols, that may have been lost on the the Christian originators of the upside-down cross, but was picked up on in the post-modern era by artists.

Comment: One of my favorite passages on this type of inversion comes from the Wasteland: "A woman drew her long black hair out tight / And fiddled whisper music on those strings / And bats with baby faces in the violet light / Whistled, and beat their wings / And crawled head downward down a blackened wall / And upside down in air were towers / Tolling reminiscent bells, that kept the hours / And voices ringing out of empty cisterns and exhausted wells. "

Answer (score 6):

The earliest one I could find was [Eugène Vintras](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eug%C3%A8ne_Vintras#/media/File:Vintras,_Eugene.jpg)(page only available in french) .

Vintras was a French Gnostic revivalist from the around the middle of the 19th century **(1807–1875)**.
He preached the end of the world, and claimed he had received messages from the Archangel Michael and that he himself was a reincarnation of Elijah. Vintras was condemned by the Vatican, and after his condemnation he started using an upside down cross. The mention of this being satanic comes from [Éliphas Lévi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89liphas_L%C3%A9vi) (an occultist himself) stating that Vintras' inverted cross was "**indicative of satanic influences**"

[<sub>Cult and Ritual Abuse: Narratives, Evidence, and Healing Approaches, 3rd Edition
By James Randall Noblitt Ph.D., Pamela Perskin Noblitt</sub>](https://books.google.nl/books?id=JhiDBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA161&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> Vintras, following further attacks from the Church, adopted the
>   **inverted cross** as the symbol of the new dispensation of which he was
>   the prophet, **inverted because the Reign of the Suffering Christ had
>   been superseded by the Reign of the Holy Spirit of Love.**
>
> [<sub>Blood in the City: Violence and Revelation in Paris, 1789-1945
>   By Richard D. E. Burton, Professor of French and Francophone Studies Richard D E Burton</sub>](https://books.google.nl/books?id=qy1Wp2T3KqgC&pg=PA164&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

<sub>image courtesy of Wikipedia</sub>

[image: Vintras]

There is also a [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/45537/44098) similar to yours on the Christianity SE with more sources.